# chmod 777 based on directory

Tags: terminal, chmod, cronjob

I am wanting to perhaps create a cronjob that will monitor a directory and will do automatically chmod 777 and files that are created inside the directory or a subdirectory of my main directory. Is this possible?

Comment: run `crontab -e` as root ... then add `0 * * * *    chmod -R 777 /directory/to/chng_mod` .. that would `chmod -R 777` every hour of every day ... would this not work?

Comment: Thank you txtechhelp, I think perhaps I was trying to overly complicate something that should have been relatively simple.

Answer (score 0):

0 * * * * chmod -R 777 /directory/to/chng_mod

This would chmod -R 777 every hour of the day to the specified directory.